# Find a matrix A such that $\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{m} \|A\|_{\infty}$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Find a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that $\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{m} \|A\|_{\infty}$. (It can be shown that $\|A\|_2 \leq \sqrt{m} \|A\|_{\infty}$ in general.) The example should work for any $m$ and $n$.

I can't think of anything to even start with.

Comment: How about looking at the proof of $\|A\|_2\le\sqrt m\|A\|_\infty$ and see where the inequality is tight.

Comment: try any identity matrix or related ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality holds because for every nonzero vector $x$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{m}\,\|Ax\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty}
\ge \frac{\sqrt{m}\,\|Ax\|_\infty}{\|x\|_2}
\ge \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}.\tag{1}
$$
So, for $\sqrt{m}\|A\|_\infty=\|A\|_2$, you need $\|x\|_2=\|x\|_\infty$ and $\sqrt{m}\,\|Ax\|_\infty= \|Ax\|_2$ at some $x$ which maximises both the LHS and the RHS of $(1)$. The former equality means that $x$, up to a multiple, is the $k$-th standard basis vector $e_k$. In turn, the latter equality means that all entries of the $k$-th column of $A$ have the same magnitudes, and $\|A\|_\infty=|a_{ik}|$ for every $i$. However, for $e_k$ to be a maximiser of $\|Ax\|_\infty/\|x\|_\infty$, all other columns of $A$ must be zero, otherwise for every $j\ne k$ such that $Ae_j$ is nonzero, we have $\|A(e_k+t e_j)\|_\infty>\|Ae_k\|_\infty$ when $t\ne0$ is sufficiently small and its sign is chosen appropriately.

In short, $A$ has at most one nonzero column and all entries in this column have identical magnitudes.